# write a method called removeZeros

Tags: java

Write a method that eliminates all occurrences of the number 0. The method I Wrote works, unless there are two zeros in a row, what am I doing wrong e.g 0,7,2,0,0,4,0 after running it though the method outputs 7,2,0,4?

```
    import java.util.*;

public class RemoveZeros {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] nums = {0, 7, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0};
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(nums));

    removeZeros(list);
    System.out.println(list);
} 
public static void removeZeros(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i) == 0) {
            list.remove(i);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: you have to manually decrease your `i`.

Comment: Try instead of your for-loop this: `int i = list.size() - 1; while (i >= 0) { ... i--;}`

Comment: Do it by hand on paper: try 1, 0, 0, 2

Comment: @Blobonat except that `i--` is executed after the loop body, not before.

Comment: @AndyTurner Corrected it.

Comment: @Blobonat why not just stick with the for loop, like before: `for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting `i--;` after `list.remove(i);`

```
    ...
    list.remove(i);
    i--;
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a single statement as following:

```
public static void removeZeros(ArrayList<Integer> list) {

    list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(0));

  }
```

for using `Collection`, import following:

```
import java.util.Collections;
```

Answer (score 0):

The remove method for ArrayLists

> Removes the element at the specified position in this list. Shifts
>   any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their
>   indices).
>   [(Javadocs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Thus, when you are removing an element from the list in the code as it is written, you have shifted all elements to the right of removed element *i* to the left; *i+1* gets shifted to position *i*, but you still increment *i* at the end of the loop, so it effectively skips over the next value in the list, which it what you are noticing with the following 0.

You have options here.  You can either keep the loop going forward and change the if statement to:

```
if (list.get(i) == 0) {
    list.remove(i);
    i--;
}
```

Which will set *i* to *i-1* so when you loop through again, *i* is back to its original value and accounts for the shift that just occurred, OR

You can start at the ending of the list, and go through it in reverse order, in which case the shift won't matter as you have already passed those elements:

```
for (int i = list.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (list.get(i) == 0) {
        list.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because when you remove a Zero, the cursor is still moving.  So it will skip the element after the Zero.  To handle this move the cursor a step back when you remove a zero.  Add i--; after the list.remove(i) statement.